# Preprecessing for Embedding: transforming word tokens to integer vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, word-embedding

I am trying to preprocess a corpus of text for input to a word embedding layer, which takes padded vectors of integers.

I know Keras/Tensorflow already has a list of functions that can do this (e.g., https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/#one_hot). But I would like to do my custom tokenization. This will be useful if the language is not English, for example.

Does anyone know of examples of code that can take in a list of tokens, and transform them to vectors of integers? I would think this is a fairly common NLP task, so I wanted to check before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Sklearn has a [bunch of text preprocessing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) functionality. You could also look at NLTK for custom stopwords, or Gensim for probabilistic vectorization. It really depends on your use-case and might help to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks @G.Anderson - I remembered Keras's IMDB dataset preprocessing code also has some of this functionality: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/imdb.py